# Impact of matrix sparsity on cblas sgemm in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: cuda, ubuntu-14.04, blas, cublas

I have recently discovered that the performance of a cblas_sgemm call for matrix multiplication dramatically improves if the matrices have a "large" number of zeros in them. It improves to the point that it beats its cublas cousin by around 100 times. This could be most probably attributed to some **automatic detection of sparsity** and suitable format conversion by cblas_sgemm function.

Unfortunately, no such behavior is exhibited by its cuda counterpart i.e. cublasSgemm.

So, the question is, how can I get the same type of optimization on cublasSgemm for matrices that **may have** a large number of zeros.

And what technique does cblas_sgemm use to automatically adjust to sparse matrices?

Please, do not recommend cuSparse / CUSP etc because

1. I am not sure about the sparsity of input matrices beforehand
2. I am working on an iterative algorithm where for initial few iterations the matrices **may be** sparse but gradually become dense as time goes on.

Thanks in advance

**Edited to include code to reproduce the above scenario**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <cblas.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
const int m = 5000; 

timespec blas_start, blas_end, cublas_start, cublas_end;
long totalnsec; //total nano sec
double totalsec, totaltime;
int i, j;
float *A = new float[m]; // 1 x m
float *B = new float[m*m]; // m x m
float *C = new float[m]; // 1 x m

// input martix A: every 32nd element is non-zero
for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
{       
    A[i] = 0;
    if( i % 32 == 0)    //adjust for sparsity
        A[i] = i;
}

// input matrix B: identity matrix
// col major = row major
for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        if (i==j)           
            B[j*m + i] = 1;
        else
            B[j*m + i] = 0;     
    }

clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &blas_start);
cblas_sgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, 1, m, m, 1, A, m, B, m, 0, C, m);
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &blas_end);
    /*
for(i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    printf("%f ", C[i]);
    */

//cublas section

cudaError_t cudaStat;   
cublasHandle_t handle;
cublasCreate(&handle);
//Declaring Device Variables
float *A_d, *B_d, *C_d;

//Allocating Memory for Device Variables
cudaStat = cudaMalloc(&A_d, sizeof(float)*m);
if(cudaStat != cudaSuccess) printf("Error Allocating Memory for A_d\n");

cudaStat = cudaMalloc(&B_d, sizeof(float)*m*m);
if(cudaStat != cudaSuccess) printf("Error Allocating Memory for B_d\n");

cudaStat = cudaMalloc(&C_d, sizeof(float)*m);
if(cudaStat != cudaSuccess) printf("Error Allocating Memory for C_d\n");

// Moving values of A, B onto Device variables
cublasSetVector(m, sizeof(float), A, 1, A_d, 1);
cublasSetMatrix(m, m, sizeof(float), B, m, B_d, m); 

// Do the actual multiplication
float alpha = 1.0f, beta = 0.0f;
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &cublas_start);

cublasSgemm(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, 1, m, m, &alpha, A_d, 1, B_d, m, &beta, C_d, 1);

cudaDeviceSynchronize();
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &cublas_end);

cublasGetVector(m, sizeof(float), C, 1, C_d, 1);
    /*
for(i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    printf("%f ", C[i]);
    */

// Print times
// blas time
totalsec = (double)blas_end.tv_sec - (double)blas_start.tv_sec;
totalnsec = blas_end.tv_nsec - blas_start.tv_nsec;
if(totalnsec < 0)
{
    totalnsec += 1e9;
    totalsec -= 1;
}
totaltime = totalsec + (double)totalnsec*1e-9;
cout<<"BLAS Time = "<< totaltime << "\n";

//cublas
totalsec = (double)cublas_end.tv_sec - (double)cublas_start.tv_sec;
totalnsec = cublas_end.tv_nsec - cublas_start.tv_nsec;
if(totalnsec < 0)
{
    totalnsec += 1e9;
    totalsec -= 1;
}
totaltime = totalsec + (double)totalnsec*1e-9;
cout<<"CUBLAS Time = "<< totaltime << "\n";

return 0;
}
```

Ran it to get the following results

```
malang@ubuntu:~/uas/stackoverflow$ nvcc -arch=sm_12 blascomp.cu -o blascomp.o -lblas -lcublas
malang@ubuntu:~/uas/stackoverflow$ ./blascomp.o
BLAS Time = 0.000964504
CUBLAS Time = 0.0365322
```

**EDIT**

**Edited after the answer of @Eric**

Use of cublasSgemv has greatly enhanced the performance on the GPU. But, I still have this problem of cblas_sgemm being much more efficient for **sparse matrices** on the CPU. What could be the possible reasons?

**EDIT Executed the following commands on the suggestion of @Eric @osgx @Robert Crovella**

```
erisp@ubuntu:~/uas/stackoverflow$ ldd ./gemmcomp.o
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb76f6000)
    libblas.so.3 => /usr/lib/libblas.so.3 (0xb765e000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb7576000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb73c7000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xb7381000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb76f7000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb7364000)

erisp@ubuntu:~/uas/stackoverflow$ ll -d /usr/lib/libblas* /etc/alternatives/libblas.*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 مارچ  13  2015 /etc/alternatives/libblas.a -> /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   27 مارچ  13  2015 /etc/alternatives/libblas.so -> /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   29 مارچ  13  2015 /etc/alternatives/libblas.so.3 -> /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   29 مارچ  13  2015 /etc/alternatives/libblas.so.3gf -> /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 مارچ  13  2015 /usr/lib/libblas/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   27 مارچ  13  2015 /usr/lib/libblas.a -> /etc/alternatives/libblas.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   28 مارچ  13  2015 /usr/lib/libblas.so -> /etc/alternatives/libblas.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   30 مارچ  13  2015 /usr/lib/libblas.so.3 -> /etc/alternatives/libblas.so.3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   32 مارچ  13  2015 /usr/lib/libblas.so.3gf -> /etc/alternatives/libblas.so.3gf
```

Comment: '100 times'? Which implementation of `clbas_sgemm` are you using? Can you give a code to reproduce that?

Comment: I have uploaded the complete code, please give it a try - @Eric

Comment: malang, what was the linking command? Which cblas implementation are you using? What is output of `ldd ./blascomp.o` ? What is the version of ubuntu?

Comment: cuda v 5.0. architecture = sm_12

Comment: ubuntu 12.0, @Eric how do i check cblas implementation version?

Comment: nvcc -arch=sm_12 blascomp.cu -o blascomp.o -lblas -lcublas was the linking command @osgx

Comment: @Eric, can you please fill A with all non-zeros and then check the results? Does it have an impact on cblas_sgemm performance? Will be most grateful

Comment: @malang as @osgx said `ldd ./blascomp.o`

Comment: Thanks @Eric and osgx.  ldd ./blascomp.o shows "libblas.so.3 => /usr/lib/libblas.so.3".

Comment: @malang your code has a problem. see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a problem - you are using the wrong BLAS API. You use the matrix-matrix-multiplication routine `gemm()` to do a vector-matrix-multiplication operation.

For vec-mat-mul or mat-vec-mul you should use `gemv()`. Of course `gemm()` can give correct result with a matrix having only 1 row. But this is an unexpected corner case that `gemv()` should handle,
so you may not get the peak performance on GPU and/or CPU.

You could change to `gemv()` and benchmark again.

---

**EDIT**

Here's my benchmark result with single thread MKL. Values of `A` and `B` are same as in your code. I cannot reproduce your result of '0.000964504s' on CPU. You could check the correctness of your result vector. There's a chance that your cblas library has a bug.

Using `gemm()`

```
BLAS Time = 0.0169784
CUBLAS Time = 0.00356155
```

Using `gemv()`

```
BLAS Time = 0.0167557
CUBLAS Time = 0.0013809
```

**EDIT2**

I now can reproduce the FAST result on unbuntu 14.04 with the package `libblas-dev`.

The reason is answered in the following question.

[cblas gemm time dependent on input matrix values - Ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38042451/cblas-gemm-time-dependent-on-input-matrix-values-ubuntu-14-04)

In the particular version of BLAS, there's code to check for zero element. The checking cost is O(n^2), so it is worth doing this on matrix-matrix multiplication whose cost is O(n^3).

For GPU gemm(), as the order of computing is different (block by block instead of line by line), such optimization may not be feasible. But it is doable for GPU gemv(), where the time spent on loading the matrix from global memory could be saved.

Comment: Replaced with "cublasSgemv(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, m, m, &alpha, B_d, m, A_d, 1, &beta, C_d, 1);". For dense vector A: BLAS Time = 0.0291584, CUBLAS Time = 0.00639274, which is good, BUT....

Comment: you are right blas -> cblas_sgemv(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, m, m, 1, B, m, A, 1, 0, C, 1); and cublas -> cublasSgemv(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, m, m, &alpha, B_d, m, A_d, 1, &beta, C_d, 1); Results: BLAS Time = 0.0300957, CUBLAS Time = 0.00634591

Comment: You mean never replace gemv with gemm.

Comment: Yes, never replace gemv with gemm.

Comment: could you please verify the arguments of this call to be correct for A=1xm, B=mxm and C=1xm? cblas_sgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, 1, m, m, 1.0f, A, m, B, m, 0.0f, C, m); I mean could it be possible that I might be accessing out of bounds memory?

Comment: Use of cublasSgemv has greatly enhanced the performance on the GPU. But, I still have this problem of cblas_sgemm being much more efficient for **sparse matrices**. What could be the possible reasons?

Comment: @RobertCrovella Would you PLEASE run the code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38042451/cblas-gemm-time-dependent-on-input-matrix-values?noredirect=1#comment63524988_38042451 just once. I will be EXTREMELY GRATEFUL. Please, could you give a few hints for the possible reasons for this bizarre behaviour. I have tested this code on another computer - same ubuntu flavour - with the same results

Comment: Done, commented there.  I can't explain the behavior or offer any suggestions.  As Eric has already suggested, it would be useful to know the actual blas that is being used in your case.

Comment: @RobertCrovella edited questions to add some more info

Comment: I took a look at the default blas implementation in Ubuntu 14.04 and it does have an optimization for the cases where certain matrix elements are exactly zero.  I've updated your other question with an answer detailing my findings.  So I retracted my previous statement (comment).

Comment: 'But it is doable for GPU gemv(), where the time spent on loading the matrix from global memory could be saved.' could you please elaborate a bit. Do you mean that we should check each element of the vector for being '0' before calling cublas gemv? Would that save time for vectors with MANY zeros @Eric

Comment: @malang No. it means you could implement the kernel function gemv() by yourself, and apply this optimization strategy to it.

Comment: @Eric it takes more time just to spawn 'm' threads without any code than it takes cblas_sgemm to multiply those matrices.

Comment: @malang what do you mean? where does the 'threads' thing come from?

Comment: @Eric I mean I would need at least 'm' threads in cuda to implement an optimized version of cublasSgemv for this situation. But, just creating 'm' threads of a simple kernel on the GPU without any code takes more time than cblas_sgemm to multiply 'these' matrices on the host. But, I have 'grown up' under the impression that for large matrix multiplications GPUs are better.

Comment: @Eric 'm' being number of elements in the vector

Comment: @malang I cannot agree. Empty kernel with m threads takes less then 1e-5s usually.

Comment: @Eric I shouldn't have said 'more time'. I should have said 'of the same order'. Maybe its dependent on the system. With m = 6000 with 95% 0s, cblas_sgemm takes 7.8964e-05 sec. While it takes cuda 2.3e-5 sec to create 6000 thousand threads of an empty kernel